# firefox does not send the cookie for https request: works fine in chrome

Tags: express, firefox, cookies

I have an app working fine in chrome for both http(localhost) and https(heroku), but firefox does not set the cookie over https(heroku). It works fine on http(localhost) (Express Server)

app.js

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'secretKey123',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
cookie: { maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000 }}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); next();});
```

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/remove/' + id,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            var dataOj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#total-price').html("Total: Rs. " + dataOj.total);
            $('.cart-qty').html(dataOj.qty);
            $('#' + id).remove();
            if ($('.cart-items tr').length === 1) {
                $('.cart-panel').html('<h2>Your Cart is Empty.</h2>');
            }
```

Comment: Does it receive the header that tries to set the cookie? (Use dev tools to check.) Does it show the cookie in the cookies for the site? Does the same thing happen when you use private browsing, with any extensions that might interfere disabled?

Comment: Yes, both in chrome and firefox, I get the set-cookie header. I can find the cookies in both the browsers. The set-cookie header in response is there even in private browsing.

Comment: Your AJAX request is cross-domain? Then you need to set the `withCredentials` flag for cookies to work properly.

Comment: CBroe - I edited my question. Sorry for not being specific earlier